# Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, Position 1. when trying to load Sitecore instance with Solr Configuration

Tags: solr, lucene, sitecore, solrnet, sitecore8.1

I have configured solr in my local machine and it is up and running on the port: 9999 after creating required Solr Cores for Sitecore. Then, I disabled all Lucene config files and enabled all Solr Config files in Include folder. Also, Global.asax is also updated with CastleWindsor solr provider. After making these changes and trying to load my sitecore instance, it threw me the following error:

**Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, Position 1.**

Reference I followed: https://soen.ghost.io/setting-up-solr-for-sitecore-8-x/

Please help me out of this issue.

Comment: It's not in the steps you've mentioned, but I assume you've done it. Did you patch/change the hostname (`ContentSearch.Solr.ServiceBaseAddress`) for Solr in the Sitecore configuration files?

My other thought is that the core names don't match up between Solr and configuration, shooting in the dark on this one as there's not much information to go on :).

Comment: Thanks @JasonBert for the reply. I had updated the ServiceBaseAddress to the port where the solr is running(9999). Also, where I need to check the difference in core names in configuration files?

Comment: Sounds like your Solr instance isn't returning what the parser expects it to do - usually this is caused by a misconfiguration of Solr or another error, so it returns a 404 or a 500 error - which is HTML and not XML.

Comment: Two things:

1) Can you provide the stack trace of your error, this should indicate whether it's a configuration issue or not
2) Each index has a corresponding `<index id="sitecore_core_index" ...>` node. Inside that is a `<param desc="core">$(id)</param>` node, usually its value is `$(id)`, which in this case would be `sitecore_core_index`. You either need to make sure the cores in Solr match those default core names in the configuration or patch in the core names you've set up in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error a few times. The explanation is quite straight forward.

Older versions of Solr use XML as default, while now JSON is the default. Simply add wt=json.

The fix is by adding an extra parameter

```
param.Add(KV.Create("wt", "xml"));
```

This has been [fixed in SolrNet](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/pull/322) in newer versions, so pull from NuGet and it sohuld work